# What is the cardinality of the set of all intervals of real numbers?

Tags: analysis, set-theory

I am currently reading the following in "*Probabilistic Machine Learning*", in section **2.2.2 Continuous random variables**:

> ... If X ∈ R is a real-valued quantity, it is called a continuous random variable. In this case, we can
> no longer create a finite (or countable) set of distinct possible values it can take on. **However, there
> are a countable number of intervals which we can partition the real line into**. If we associate events
> with X being in each one of these intervals, we can use the methods discussed above for discrete
> random variables. Informally speaking, we can represent the probability of X taking on a specific
> real value by allowing the size of the intervals to shrink to zero, as we show below.

I 'm not sure how to interpret the bold part. Does it mean that the set $I=\{(a,b) | a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is countably infinite or something else? To me it seems as if it should be at least as large as $\mathbb{R}$, as you can create an injection $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow I$ where $f(x) = (x,x+c), x \in \mathbb{R}$.

For the textbook, a draft pdf file is available here: https://probml.github.io/pml-book/book1.html

Comment: The half-open  intervals $[m,m+1)$, for $m\in \mathbb Z$ partition the line, for instance.

Comment: I think they are saying, sloppily: Any partition of the real line into intervals must consist of at most countably many intervals. This assumes non-trivial intervals (intervals with at least two points.)

Comment: It just sounds wrong to me. You are certainly right that there are uncountably many distinct real intervals. The term "partition" is not explained and I don't know whether the author intends the standard meaning of a partition as presentation of a set as a collection of pairwise disjoint non-empty subsets. I suspect what the author means is for any desired precision, you can partition the rules into countably many intervals, such that the interval a random variable lies in identifies the random variable to the desired precision. Why not send the author a comment?

Comment: The wording is a bit ambiguous.  I take it to mean: If we *partition* the real numbers into intervals the set of such intervals *in that particular partition* is countable.  That is if $U= \{[a_\alpha,b_\alpha)\}$ and the intervals are disjoint and $\mathbb R= \cup_{\alpha}[a_\alpha, b_\alpha)$ then we have a countably infinite number of intervals.  However if I take it *literally* it sounds like it is saying if we can't all the possible intervals we could use of *all* possible ways to partition the reals there are countably many intervals.  That's obviously false for the reason you give.

Comment: There are uncountably many intervals.  And every interval can you used in *some* partition.  But no partition can use all intervals.  (In fact, if a partition uses the interval $[a,b]$ then it can not use any other interval containing *any* of the points between $a$ and $b$).  In any one partition, that one partition will countain only countably many intervals.

Comment: Anyhoo... to answer your question "What is the cardinality of the set of all intervals of real numbers" the answer is "the same cardinality of the reals".  I'll leave the proof/argument to you but will not your argument it must be at least equal to the reals is absolutely correct; I'll leave it to you to fine tune the argument as to why it is not a high cardinality.

Comment: @fleablood So, is it possible to create a partition with uncountably infinite intervals?

Comment: @Enk9456  Actually, no, it is not.  Although it is not trivial to demonstrate that.  The gyst of the argument though is every interval will have a finite but non-zero measurable length and we can't have an *uncountable* sum of positive non-zero measures.  If we partition the reals to an uncountable number of sets (which obviously we can do) then only a countable number of them can have positive measure and an uncountable many of them must have zero measure. That's not trivial but if you think about it it is intuitive.

Comment: ... and an *interval* $(a,b)$ must, by definition, have length equal to $L = b - a > 0$.  A set of measure $0$ can not be an *interval*.

Comment: @fleablood Note that some texts do allow singleton intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they mean is, if you fix a certain small distance $r$, then $\Bbb R=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}[nr,(n+1)r)$. You are absolutely right that a more general set of "all intervals" is uncountable. By controlling $r$, you can control the fineness of your discrete probability approximation.

Comment: To get a partition (into disjoint sets) those intervals should be half open.

Comment: So you or the OP should be sending the author a comment saying that this statement in his draft has led to some confusion. I don't think it is so obvious that what you propose is the actual intention (although it seems plausible to me).

Comment: As a related and last question, is the set of all possible partitions of R (where each partition is a set of disjoint intervals, the union of which result to R) also uncountable?

Comment: *All* possible? Yes. For instance, my simple example can be done for all $r\gt0$, and this is an uncountable set

Comment: Regarding half-open intervals, given the probabilistic nature of the book in question it is possible that the book author does not care about *half-open* versus *closed* because endpoint values are taken on with probability zero. The author would then be free to use a more informal "calculus 1" meaning of partition, meaning a sequence of closed intervals abutting end-to-end.

Comment: If I understanding correctly, a way to rephrase the bold text could also be: "For any partition S of the real numbers (made of disjoint intervals), the partition S has a countable number of intervals."

Comment: @Enk9456 That isn't necessarily true. It just means we can do it in a countable way, if we want. Countability isn't guaranteed

Comment: An example of an uncountable partition of, e.g. $[0,1)$, is the partition taken by elements of all equivalence classes $[0,1)/_{\sim}$ where $x\sim y\iff x-y\in\Bbb Q$

Comment: I'd say what "For any partition S of the real numbers (made of disjoint intervals), the partition S has a countable number of intervals" is true but in a jailhouse lawyer sort of way.  A partition need not have *any* intervals.  Or it may have just a finite number of intervals. Or it can have infinitely many intervals but other sets as well.  As zero *is* a countable number and we can't have uncountably many intervals it is technically a true statement... it may be worth noting every interval has uncountably many points.